# White tkinter window screen when trying to display image

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run the following code, I don't get any errors, but I get a white screen without the image. I am expecting it to display the image on full screen.
I checked the image and everything is good with that.
Does someone know why this is happening?

The code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

window_width = root.winfo_width()
window_height = root.winfo_height()

image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Proggramers Club\screenshot.png")
resized_image = image.resize((window_width, window_height))

photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

label = tk.Label(frame, image=photo_image)
label.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `root.update_idletasks()` (if it doesn't work use `root.update()`) before the `root.winfo_width()`. Right now both `window_width` and `window_height` are `1` and not the screen's width/height

Comment: you could also `bind` function to event `<Configure>` and this function should resize image because it will be executed after creating window. This function will be also executed when you resize window - so it may resize image when you resize window.

Answer (score 2):

##### Why is this happening?

That is because `root.winfo_width()` and `root.winfo_height()` indeed give you the window size, but when you create the window (`root  = tk.Tk()`) it is not fully realized and/or configured and then hides it to make the coding experience more pythonic.
Since you're trying to get the size of it before the mainloop or any other update methods `winfo_width` and `winfo_height` will just give you the unrealized/unconfigured values which will likely be `1` for both of them.
<sub>*Also if you add some Widget or configuration the windows values wont change until it gets updated*</sub>

##### Solution

Luckily you're making it fullscreen so you can use `root.winfo_screenwidth()` and `root.winfo_screenheight()` instead.

Or you do what [TheLizzard said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266335/white-tkinter-window-screen/77266466#comment136215568_77266335): Call `root.update()` or `root.update_idletasks()` before you get the window size

Comment: I think this might be a bit incorrect as `root.winfo_id()` gives an `int` before the `mainloop`/`update`/`update_idletasks`. Therefore, the window must exists but maybe it's not fully set up yet?

Comment: @TheLizzard from what I understand the window isn't created when you call `tk.Tk()` it only creates the Tcl interpreter no window. So the values you are getting are probably just created by tkinter so you can configure (or whatever) it better

Comment: From my understanding, the `winfo_id()` value is the id of the window which isn't assigned by `tcl` but by the window manager on the system (eg `x11`, Window's window manager). Other processes can interact with that id even if they have no idea who (`tcl`) created the window. I might be completely wrong so until we can get an expert, I will consider myself wrong.

Comment: @TheLizzard I investigated a bit and you where more right but I wasn't completely wrong. `tk.Tk()` does create the window imediatly, but also hides it untill `mainloop` or one of the other functions is called. This is done because the devs of tkinter wanted it the Pythonic way (`Explicit is better than implicit` - The Zen of Python). That would also explain why `root.winfo_width()` returns `1` instead of `0` or `None`

Comment: Never thought of it that way but it makes sense and explains the `1`. Nice research.